# Reduce space between legend text and icon in Highchart

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

Is it possible to reduce the space between the number and icon? I am using angular 8 and highchart. Below is the chart legend config. 
[image]

```
this.legend = {
  align: 'center',
  verticalAlign: 'bottom',
  layout: 'horizontal',
  symbolRadius: 0,
  symbolHeight: 8,
  reversed: true,
  padding: 3,
  itemStyle: {
    color: '#000000',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    fontFamily: 'Roboto'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for [`symbolPadding`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.symbolPadding) option

> The pixel padding between the legend item symbol and the legend item
>   text.
>
> **Defaults** to 5.

```
legend: {
    symbolPadding: 1
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/s5d0ry2t/